# Discussion board post display

Tags: discussion-board, display-name

When someone posts a message in discussion board, his/her name appears on the left along with Photo, if available. Suppose the site owner/admin changes the post, then only the name of the person who changed the post rather than who created appears. Is it possible to force the view setting such that only "created by" is shown rather than "last modified by"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be possible through the SharePoint UI. You will need to customize or create a new view for the discussion library in SharePoint Designer to change how the view renders.